# Query exceeded resource limits when merging data from two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables t1 & t2.  I want to take everything From t1, and only Hour column from t2. My query is as below:
SELECT t1.*,t2.Hour FROM t1, t2

It shows me the query exceeded resource limits. What is the best way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.*, t2.hour
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING (date, id, device, cost)
```

Comment: @Mikhali, Thanks for the help. After joining I'm unable to get the correct cost. Can you please assist? There are 54065468 rows in t1 and 46034100 rows in t2. After joining, I got different number of rows.

Comment: looks like not all entries in t1 have respective entries in t2, so you should try left join then

Comment: @ Mikhali, still there is a varaitions before and after join

Comment: then try to work more on your question and provide sufficient details so we can further help.

Comment: @ Mikhali, Actually I pulled data from Campaign Manager. t1 has: Date,  Campaign_ID, Country, City, Platform_Type,Cost. .                                                                                                                                                     
     Table t2 has: Date, Hour, Platform_Type, Campaign_ID,Cost . Both table has the same date range. t1 doesn't have Hour dimension. That's why I'd like to take everything from t1 and Hour from t2. Hope you could help me.

Comment: @Mikhali. Thanks for your help. I have a new post where I need to remove duplicate rows in table. Could you please help me.

Comment: Thanks Mikhali. Sorry i forgot. I've accepted the answer and it was helpful for me.